# Removeclass in foreach with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

when I click on a profile in the foreach loop, the "active" property of all "active" classes is deleted, not just the profile I clicked. How can I fix it so that only what I click is deleted? I do not want all "active" classes to be deleted, but only the active class property you clicked.

```
@foreach($other_user['details'] as $user)
                  @php
                  $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
                  $withid= $user->id;
                  $getunreadcount = \Models\Members::getlastconverunread($user_id,$withid);
                  @endphp
                  
                 <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-conversation="{{$user->lastConver != null ? 'true' :'false'}}"  data-id="{{ $user->username }}" @if($getunreadcount > 0) class="list-group-item list-group-item-action border-0 active userlink {{$user->lastConver != null ? ' ' :'hidden'}}" @else class="list-group-item list-group-item-action border-0 userlink {{$user->lastConver  != null ? ' ' :'hidden'}}" @endif >
              
                <div class="d-flex align-items-start">
                  @if($user->user_photo!='')
                  <img src="{{ url('/') }}/public/storage/users/{{ $user->user_photo }}" class="rounded-circle mr-1" alt="{{ $user->username }}" width="40" height="40">
                  @else
                  <img class="rounded-circle mr-1" width="40" height="40" src="{{ url('/') }}/public/img/no-user.png" alt="{{ $user->username }}" />
                  @endif
                  <div class="flex-grow-1 ml-3">
                    <span class="userName">
                      {{ $user->username }}
                    </span>
                    @if($getunreadcount > 0)
                    <div class="small unread"><span class="badge badge-warning">{{$getunreadcount}} Yeni Mesaj</span></div>
                    @endif
                  </div>
                  
                </div>
              </a>
       @endforeach
```

JQUERY:

```
$('.userlink').click(function(e) {

  e.preventDefault();
        var id = $(this).data("id");
        var token = $("meta[name='csrf-token']").attr("content");
        $('.userlink').removeClass('active');

        var $this = $(this);
        if (!$this.hasClass('active')) {
          $this.removeClass('active');
        }

});
```

I will be glad if you help me thank you.

Comment: With `$('.userlink').removeClass('active');` you remove the “active” class from all userlinks. With the specific check you do on the following lines, I think you can just remove this one line and that should fix it.

Comment: Your last lines of `jQuery` code make no sense: if there's no `active` class remove `active`class. Also when you make a class list in `blade` file, you can put the condition only to `active` class and not duplicate every other. Like `class="list-group-item ... @if($getunreadcount > 0) active @endif"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.userlink').click(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    ...
    // Like this:
    $(this).removeClass('active');
});
```